# cipher class and mcrypt_create_iv is slow at times

Tags: php, mcrypt, encryption

I am having an issue with my cipher class.  At times it is very fast.  Sometimes however it is slow.  the code Im using is as follows

```
class Cipher {
    private $securekey, $iv;
    function __construct() {
        $this->securekey = hash('sha256','51(^8k"12cJ[6&cvo3H/!2s02Uh46vuT4l7sc7a@cZ27Q',TRUE);
        $this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32);
    }
    function encrypt($input) {
        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
    function decrypt($input) {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
    function storeIV() {
        return $this->iv;
    }
}
```

Are there any suggestions on why this may be slow at times and how I could fix this?

Comment: What is server load like when it runs fast?  When it runs slow?  What kinds of times have you recorded?

Comment: Server loads have been identical between fast/slow  when it is quick it is loading in about .5 seconds   when it is slow, I can wait for about 2 minutes

Comment: Just a security note: I believe you are using your Cipher class to encrypt multiple plaintext. Normally an iv should not be reused, so it is better I think to generate the IV in the encrypt method rather in the constructor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821195/use-of-initialization-vector-in-openssl-encrypt to see how to store and restore it. Also, note that mcrypt_create_iv can be very slow if the system has not enough entropy. Personally I use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes. Also, I think there is the iv argument missing in your mcrypt_encrypt/decrypt function calls.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried the three different second arguments for [`mcrypt_create_iv()`](https://www.php.net/mcrypt_create_iv): `MCRYPT_RAND` (system random number generator), `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM` (read data from /dev/random) and `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` (read data from /dev/urandom)? Do they offer different consistent speeds? I wonder if it's because /dev/random (the default random source) is running out of collected entropy; the function will block when it does.

Comment: If it's the latter, is there a solution for this or should we just change to `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` ?

Comment: @Silver89: just change to `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM`.  According to Bruce Schneier, neither /dev/random nor /dev/urandom are very robust ( https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/10/insecurities_in.html ), so you might as well use the one that works.

Comment: I used `MCRYPT_RAND` which worked. `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` also worked.

Comment: @Crontab At this time `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` are robust enough for practical security in applications. Equivocation is not advisable as it may mislead. The Schneirer link is referring to a research paper which suggests strengthening PRNGs according to a new level of robustness which would be secure against sophisticated theoretical attacks. It's proactive research, beyond state of the art at this time.

Answer (score 6):

Use MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM when creating the IV.  It's less secure, but won't block if entropy gets too low.  MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM will wait until enough entropy is acquired to be secure.

```
// PHP < 5.6
$this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```

But in more updated versions of PHP, the default has changed and your original code should work.

```
// PHP >= 5.6
$this->iv = mcrypt_create_iv(32);   // MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM implied
```

[PHP docs: mcrypt_create_iv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) *(note on $source parameter)*:

> Note that the default value of this parameter was MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM prior to PHP 5.6.0.

And from [Ubuntu Manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man4/random.4.html):

> If  you  are  unsure  about  whether  you  should  use  /dev/random  or /dev/urandom,  then  probably you want to use the latter.  As a general rule, /dev/urandom should be  used  for  everything  except  long-lived GPG/SSL/SSH keys.

Comment: This sentiment is echoed and expanded on in the [Ubuntu manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man4/random.4.html) — and I quote: "If  you  are  unsure  about  whether  you  should  use /dev/random  or /dev/urandom,  then  probably you want to use the latter. As a general rule, /dev/urandom should be  used  for  everything  except long-lived GPG/SSL/SSH keys."

Answer (score -1):

```
class Cipher {
    private $securekey, $iv;
    function __construct() {
        $this->securekey = hash('sha256','51(^8k"12cJ[6&cvo3H/!2s02Uh46vuT4l7sc7a@cZ27Q',TRUE);
        $this->iv = isset($_SESSION['sifrem'])?$_SESSION['sifrem']:mcrypt_create_iv(34);
        $_SESSION['sifrem']=$this->iv;
    }
    function encrypt($input) {
        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
    function decrypt($input) {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->securekey, base64_decode($input), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
    function storeIV() {
        return $this->iv;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's never a good idea to reuse an IV, it will have a negative impact on how secure it is.