# Generate encrypted string that can be used directly in URLs

Tags: php, encryption

Sometimes in my forms I found my self using hidden inputs that contains some values that no need for client to know about it. (In effect even if he know is not a big problem, however I don't prefer that ... and that's way I don't need a very secure and complicated encryption stuff)

Based on some answers here ([especially this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821195/use-of-initialization-vector-in-openssl-encrypt)), I build this next Class

```
class Crypto
{

    const ENCRYPT_METHODE = "AES-256-CBC";
    const SECRET_HASH     = "25c6c7ff35b9979b151f2136cd13b0ff";

    private static function GetIV()
    {

        if (empty($_SESSION['crypto']['iv'])) {
            $iv_size                  = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
            $_SESSION['crypto']['iv'] = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        }
        return $_SESSION['crypto']['iv'];
    }

    public static function Encrypt($value)
    {
        return openssl_encrypt($value,
            self::ENCRYPT_METHODE,
            self::SECRET_HASH,
            0,
            self::GetIV());
    }

    public static function Decrypt($value)
    {
        return openssl_decrypt($value,
            self::ENCRYPT_METHODE,
            self::SECRET_HASH,
            0,
            self::GetIV());
    }
}
```

... until now `Crypto` work's good with hidden input, but sometimes it generate strings that needs to be encoded before put it in a url

So, how to improve this class to do what I need ?
or is there an other better way to encrypt<=>decrypt strings?

**EDIT**
Instead of trying to generate a valid URL string value (directly with `openssl_decrypt`), it looks that adding `urlencode` / `urldecode` to methods will work just fine, and that's how Crypto methods will looks like:

```
class Crypto{

     // ...

    public static function Encrypt($value){
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($value,
                               self::ENCRYPT_METHODE,
                               self::SECRET_HASH,
                               0,
                               self::GetIV());

        return urlencode($encrypted);
    }

    public static function Decrypt($value){
        $value = urldecode($value);
        return openssl_decrypt($value,
                               self::ENCRYPT_METHODE,
                               self::SECRET_HASH,
                               0,
                               self::GetIV());
    }
}
```

I think like that it will work fine everywhere, Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271577/generate-encrypted-string-that-can-be-used-directly-in-urls/42271620#42271620)

Comment: Can you show us how you're putting these values unto a URL?

Comment: @thebluefox that's how http://website.com/noof.php?xvalue=enctyptedString !!

Comment: I'm trying to see how you're using the methods in your class in your HTML. I know what a URL looks like.

Comment: If you just want to hide the value from "generic" users that don't have that much knowledge, simply use `base64_encode()`. If you need stronger encrryption, you are on a very good way. Watch out for deprecated functions and outdated versions of openssl. When trying tutorials about encryption/openssl, find them from 2016/2017, older stuff may use bad practice.

Comment: DanFromGermany thanks, `base64_encode` it looks enough to do what I need, and I find another way to make it work for URLs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php#103849

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `url_encode()` to make sure every chars could be passed to an url and `urldecode()` to get the chars back.

Comment: That what I use know but is this will effect the encrypted Value, so it will not be encrypted correctly ?

Comment: do you know other simple ways to encrypt/decrypt strings ?

Comment: For urls? No. For a string? I haven't searched yet.

Comment: Perfect :) then you can validate this answer and mark the topic as solved ;)