# How to prepend or append IV with phpseclib

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes, phpseclib

I'm using [phplibsec](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) to do some encryption operations. The library has a method to set the IV and I'm using it to generate a random initialization vector to use in encrypt operations. The problem is that I need to have the same IV to decrypt the data (I didn't know this aspect). Now after small code modification I want to prepend the generated IV to the encrypted data but I don't know how to proceed.

encrypt.php

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\AES;
use phpseclib\Crypt\Random;

$payload = [];
// new phpseclib AES instance
$cipher = new AES();
// set a password for the encrypt
$cipher->setPassword($password);
// IV creation
$iv = Random::string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3);
// this method of the library will make the forst part of my data unreadable without iv
$cipher->setIV($iv);
// encrypt data - here I want to prepend the iv to get it later on decrypt
$output = $cipher->encrypt("some data");
// push encrypted data into an array
array_push($payload, $output);
```

decrypt.php

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\AES;
use phpseclib\Crypt\Random;

$cipher = new AES();
$cipher->setPassword($password);
// here is my mistake - I'm creating a new IV but I need the same
$cipher->setIV(Random::string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3));
// opening the file that hold encrypted data
$payload = file_get_contents('myencrypted.file');
// I've used the : to separate each line of encrypted data with php implode()
$exploded = explode(' : ', $payload); 
// iterating over the array that hold encrypted data to decrypt them then base64_encode before pass back to the client in json.       
foreach( $exploded as $str ){
  array_push($output, base64_encode($cipher->decrypt($str) ));
}
```

The decrypt operation will give me something similar (I'm encrypting images data uri)

```
XGG”)”>hÑÏÄr*‹base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD…D8
```

I think that this part `XGG”)”>hÑÏÄr*‹` of the decrypted data is the IV?
How I can prepend or append it to the encrypted data and then extrac it when the data needs to be decrypted?Can anyone help me please?

**UPDATE**

I've followed the suggestion of Topaco in comments and now I'm able to get back the data uri but it will have the iv attached so I need to remove it. At the moment after decrypt the data uri will have this structure:

```
¸ÈouFH@¬ÆÌ~k!Eâdata:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk
```

How I will remove the part before the data:image/jpeg;base64 ?

Comment: Actually this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11821195). Although different libraries are used (openssl vs. phpseclib), this is irrelevant for the handling of the IV (see penultimate section of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12486940)): Concatenation of IV and ciphertext during encryption (`$iv.$output`), separation during decryption (with `substr()`). In the case of phpseclib it applies `$iv_size = $cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3;` which you already used when creating the IV.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for the help. If you can provide an example with phpseclib will be great. I will take a look at the question you've linked. Thank you

Comment: @Topaco Unfortunately the `$cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3` will give this problem `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class phpseclib\Crypt\AES could not be converted to string`

Comment: With this expression the IV size is determined in your `encrypt` method. Does the `encrypt` method not work?

Comment: @Topaco I've solved that problem but now I'm unable to remove the IV from the decrypted data. I'm trying with `str_replace`, `but without succes

Comment: The IV does not need to be removed from the decrypted data. You must separate IV and ciphertext **before** decrypting: `$iv = substr($data, 0, $iv_size);` and `$ciphertext = substr($data, $iv_size);` (where `$data = $iv.$output;` is the concatenated data from the encryption). After separation the ciphertext can be decrypted (using the IV).

Comment: I've done it in a different way. `$iv = substr($str, 0, $ivSize); $cipher->setIV($iv); $decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($str);` and this will mantain the iv attached to the decrypted data!

Comment: If you replace `$decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($str);` with `$ciphertext = substr($str, $ivSize);` and `$decrypted = $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext);` it should work.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the help. I've added another `substr()` passage and now all works fine.