# Laravel mcrypt timeout

Tags: php, laravel, timeout, mcrypt

**apache,php 5.5.27,laravel 4.2 ,ubuntu15.04**

My code works well on windows. But it failed on linux.

error code:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   HELP
>
> Maximum execution time of 1000 seconds exceeded
>
> in /home/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php line 55

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->getIvSize(), $this->getRandomizer());
```

I have changed the max_execution_time to 1000 but it still does not work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like your environment is having an issue with whatever is being used as `$this->getRandomizer()`. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10917845/197487

Comment: I replace the '$this->getRandomizer()' with MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM directly but still time out. In getRandomizer() if MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM is defined,then return MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM.I am now wondering if the MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM is not defined in my env.